# How to make intro activity appering only once?

Tags: android, sqlite, layout

I just created intro sample show some tips in my app with 3 fragments and it works well but it only appears to user when I made the intro activity in manifest as `"launcher"` activity. So it appears every time the user opens the app.

What I need is how to make this activity appears only the first time opening the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `SharedPreferences` and set value in that when User will open it for the first time. after that Every time user open the App you can check that variable. If that value is set then you can directly call next `Activity`.

But for this approach you have to make that `<activity>` with attribute `android:noHistory="true"`. then It will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can set an activity before your intro and using `SharedPrefereces` you can store when user open your app for the first time. In the case that is the first time you start the example activity else you start the main activity.

You can save just a boolean value [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Comment: I'was writing my answer before your answer was loaded. that's why I've suggested the same. Sorry for late.